# Jest.js - test that specific function is called by the module

Tags: javascript, jestjs

The sole purpose of index.js is to run `foo` and `bar` functions:

```
//index.js
import foo from './foo.js'
import bar from './bar.js'

foo()
bar()
```

How can I test that when running index.js both `foo` and `bar` get executed?

Answer (score 0):

pretty much straight out o the documentation here.. https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-functions.html

__tests__/index.js

```
jest.mock("../foo");
jest.mock("../bar");

const foo = require("../foo");
const bar = require("../bar");

test("functions are called", done => {
  require("../index");
  expect(foo.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
  expect(bar.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
  done();
});
```

run it

```
$ yarn test
yarn run v1.5.1
$ jest
PASS  __tests__/index.js
  ✓ functions are called (14ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.955s
Ran all test suites.
✨  Done in 1.51s.
```

file structure - there's nothing special about the require paths, if it can't find the file then your path is wrong..

```
$ tree -I node_modules
.
├── __tests__
│   └── index.js
├── bar.js
├── foo.js
├── index.js
├── package.json
└── yarn.lock
```

Comment: it says `Cannot find module '../foo' from 'index.test.js'`

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'calls' of undefined` on `expect`

Comment: we'd need to see your code, but it sounds like you're not calling `.mock.calls` on a mocked function. The code I provided works as-is for me.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would concentrate on testing `foo` and `bar` functions making sure they do what they have to do.

For example if the function foo is `()=>{ return 'foo() is working' }` I make a file called `foo.test.js` and i write 2-3 tests for it.

```
test('make sure it returns something', () => {
  expect(!foo()).toBe(false);
});
test('make sure it returns string', () => {
  var val = foo();
  expect(typeof val === 'string').toBe(true);
});
test('make sure it returns string', () => {
  expect(foo()==='foo() is working').toBe(true);
});
```

This will make sure my `foo.js` is doing what it suppose to then I make another file called index.text.js and in it I'll do my mock test

```
jest.mock("../foo");
const foo = require("../foo");

test('make sure foo is called', () => {
  expect(foo).toBeCalled();
});
test('make sure foo run only once', () => {
   expect(foo.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
});
```

Now assuming you have installed jest and have package.json configured correctly you can simply run : npm run test or if you have yarn you can just run yarn test...

Comment: can I substitute `require` for `import`?

Comment: it says `Cannot find module '../foo' from 'index.test.js'`